# Toggle Drawer from AppBar LeftIcon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm starting my first Material-UI project with ReactJS.

It has the AppBar and the Drawer working (Drawer only with swipe from left bezzel to right side).

Now I want the AppBar onLeftIconButtonTouchTap to toggle the Drawer.

This is my current code for the AppBar.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

import DrawerLeft from './DrawerLeft.jsx';

function handleTouchTap() {
    // Tried it her 
}

const AppBarTop = () => (
   <div>
        <AppBar
            title="Title"
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={handleTouchTap}
        />
        <DrawerLeft />
   </div>
);

export default AppBarTop;
```

And the DrawerLeft.jsx is as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class DrawerLeft extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
}

handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}

handleClose() {
    this.setState({open: false});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <RaisedButton
                label="Open Drawer"
                onTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
            />
            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                width={200}
                open={this.state.open}
                onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
            >
                <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

So how can I toggle the Drawer from the AppList its LeftIcon?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve it in 2 steps:

1 - You're gonna have to hold the Drawer's `open` state in your `AppBar` component, and as you may know - you wont be able to do it using a stateless/functional component.
Example of your new AppBarTop component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import DrawerLeft from './DrawerLeft.jsx';

export default class AppBarTop extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            open: false
        }
    }  
    //Toggle function (open/close Drawer)
    toggleDrawer() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title="Title"
                    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} 
                />
                <DrawerLeft open={this.state.open} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} />
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

2 - Now in the `DrawerLeft` component, instead of using `this.state.open` you are gonna use `this.props.open`. And if you want to toggle the open state, you can just call `this.props.onToggleDrawer` - since we are passing it from the parent.

You can remove the `handleToggle` and `handleClose` from the `DrawerLeft`.
And since your `DrawerLeft` component has no internal state- you can turn him into a functional/stateless component.

Comment: This worked for me. But now the 'docked' functions doesnt work

Comment: Have u changed the onRequestClose to call the parent function?

Comment: the onRequestClose on Drawer is this: onRequestClose={this.props.onToggleDrawer.bind(this)} But doesnt work

Comment: You don't need to bind it - maybe that's the problem, can u try it without the binding?

Comment: No doesnt work. Only works when I click on a menu item

Comment: Placed in new answer

Comment: @TheoBouwman oh srry - now that I saw, it's not `onRequestClose`, its `onRequestChange`and it receives the new state as argument. so you can do something like `onRequestChange={(open) => this.props.onToggleDrawer(open)}` and change a bit the parent function like:
```toggleDrawer(open) {
        this.setState({
            open: open || !this.state.open
        })
    }```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciatie it.

Comment: Now the menu doesnt close when I click on a Menu Item

Comment: Is it triggering that toggle method?  If it changes the route you could handle it on the componentDidUpdate testing if the route changed

Comment: it is not correct to do the methods binding within the render method as it binds it over and over again each time render function is executed.